# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error handling

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with this code. The code is working but when I going out of the image view I am getting the next error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()

How can I fix this? I am using api 29 so setDrawingCache is deprecated. I think that is the issue!

```
mImageView.<strike>setDrawingCacheEnabled<strike>(true);
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);





    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    mResults = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    //mColorView = findViewById(R.id.colorView);



    mImageView.<strike>setDrawingCacheEnabled<strike>(true);
    mImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);


    final Button gereed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Gereed);

    //image view on touch listener
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                //getting RGB values

                int r = Color.red(pixel);
                int g = Color.green(pixel);
                int b = Color.blue(pixel);

                //getting Hex value
                String hex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(pixel);

                //set background color of view
                //mColorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));
                mResults.setText("RGB"+ r + g + b);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

My xml file!

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="334dp"
    android:src="@drawable/colorpicker"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="344dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Gereed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gereed"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0mm"
    android:layout_height="0mm"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

MY ERROR!

```
' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1958)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1863)
    at com.example.tvlift.Activity2$1.onTouch(Activity2.java:60)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13411)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3993)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:178)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7581)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7654)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:718)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Y is currently larger than your bitMap height, adjust your Y or make bitMap height higher

Comment: Please post your logcat error message, as well as xml code.

Comment: I did add all the asked information please help?

Comment: It is not clear why you had a separate snippet of code `mImageView.<strike>setDrawingCacheEnabled<strike>(true);` in your post. Please label this - is this a separate piece of code, an error, etc? It does not look like Java, since it has `<strike>` HTML tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check inside the onTouch to handle events when your x and y extend the height and width of the image view specified in the xml layout.